# How to debug secondary files of phantomjs in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, phantomjs, visual-studio-code

I'm using the phantomjs extension using https://github.com/iradul/vscode-phantomjs-debug, which is great for getting me into the main module but I can't debug into modules in the /modules directory.

The project is setup as:

```
\parent
--main.js
\parent\modules
--processing.js
```

processing.js is pulled into main.js in the usual manner with a require at the top of main.js

I'm sure there is a setting in the .vscode/launch.json that would get me into the processing.js file, I'm just not sure what it is.

processing.js is where I handle page.onXXX functions such as page.onError, page.onResourceRequested, and page.onResourceRecieved.

This isn't a typescript project - straight js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Phantom's remote debugger is currently not resolving full paths of loaded modules VS debugger can only guess where they are. You'll have to place your modules inside `node_modules` directory. Also you'll have to put break-point inside your main module somewhere after `require` call for your modules.

Take a look at this for more info:
https://github.com/iradul/vscode-phantomjs-debug/wiki/Debug-modules

Comment: Thank you for answering - renaming modules to node_modules didn't work - is there another step such as the true node_modules/modulename/bin/ folder?

Comment: Your modules have to be placed directly inside node_modules directory, you can't put them in sub-directories.
There is no other step.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of PhantomJS ? What is your OS ?

Comment: I was using a mac but now I'm trying win10.